# Pythonic way to create closures

Tags: python, python-2.7, closures, metaprogramming, decorator

I have code that exists in a file outside of a GUI, but generates methods to be called by the GUI. For example, this file contains functions that look like:

```
# old code
def fixDictionary(dictionary, key, new_value):
    def fix():
        dictionary[key] = new_value
    return fix
```

The general approach of wrapping `dictionary` in a closure works fine, but this approach leads to a lot of boilerplate code for creating parameter-less functions. I made a simple decorator that does this for me, shown below.

```
# new code
from functools import wraps

def strip_args(function):
    def outer(*args, **kwargs):

        @wraps(function)
        def inner():
            function(*args, **kwargs)
        return inner

    return outer

@strip_args
def fixDictionary(dictionary, key, new_value):
    dictionary[key] = new_value
```

For reference, the usage of this function looks something like:

```
dictionary = {'key': 'old_value'}

fixer = fixDictionary(dictionary, 'key', 'new_value')
fixer()

print(dictionary) # {'key': 'new_value'}
```

Then, I also have a bunch of methods in my code that look like:

```
# old code
def checkDictionary(dictionary):
    errors = []
    for key, value in dictionary.items():
        if value == 'old_value':
            error.append(fixDictionary(dictionary, key, 'new_value'))
    return errors
```

If not clear, these methods check objects for errors and then return anonymous functions that the GUI can call in order to correct those errors. However, all of these methods initialize a blank container, add items to it, and then return it. In order to remove the repeated code in all of these functions, I wrote another decorator:

```
# new code
def init_and_return(**init_dict):
    if len(init_dict) != 1:
        raise ValueError('Exactly one "name=type" pair should be supplied')

    _name, _type = init_dict.items()[0]

    def outer(function):

        @wraps(function)
        def inner(*args, **kwargs):
            _value = _type()
            function.func_globals[_name] = _value
            function(*args, **kwargs)
            return _value
        return inner

    return outer

@init_and_return(errors=list)
def checkDictionary(dictionary):
    for key, value in dictionary.items():
        if value == 'old_value':
            errors.append(fixDictionary(dictionary, key, 'new_value'))
```

Now, the final usage looks something like:

```
dictionary = {'key': 'old_value'}
errors = checkDictionary(dictionary) # [<function fixDictionary at 0x01806C30>]
errors[0]()
print(dictionary) # {'key': 'new_value'}
```

This also works great and allows me avoid writing more boilerplate for these functions as well. I have two questions about the above implementation:

1. Is there a more Pythonic way to implement this functionality? The purpose is to eliminate all of the boilerplate code from each function, but writing the functions `strip_args` and `init_and_return` definitely strained the brain. While functions like this shouldn't have to be written often, it seems like they are far separated from their actual behavior.
2. The line `function.func_globals[_name] = _value` has undesired behavior; it allows `errors` to be accessed from the global scope. This isn't the end of the world because the variable is reset every time a function is called, but is there anyway for me to set a local variable instead? I have tried changing this line to `locals()[_name] = _value`, but the scope doesn't carry through to the function. Is this level of meta-programming beyond the scope of what is intended in Python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out a way to address my second question by implementing some book-keeping code into the `init_and_return` function that checks whether it's overwriting a global variable, and then restoring it if so (or deleting it if not).

```
def init_and_return(**init_dict):

    # this could be extended to allow for more than one k-v argument
    if len(init_dict) != 1:
        raise ValueError('Exactly one "name=type" pair should be supplied')

    _name, _type = init_dict.items()[0]
    def outer(function):

        @wraps(function)
        def inner(*args, **kwargs):

            # instantiate a new container
            _value = _type()

            # used to roll-back the original global variable
            _backup, _check = None, False

            # store original global variable (if it exists)
            if _name in function.func_globals:
                _backup = function.func_globals[_name]
                _check = True

            # add container to global scope
            function.func_globals[_name] = _value

            function(*args, **kwargs)

            # roll-back if it existed beforehand, delete otherwise
            if _check:
                function.func_globals[_name] = _backup
            else:
                del function.func_globals[_name]

            return _value
        return inner
    return outer
```